# Understanding the memory map in QA7 document on the official website

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, operating-systems, memory-split

[image: Memory Mapping of RPi 2]

1. The description of the first row says "GPU access". That looks confusing. Isn't the memory split for CPU and GPU usage?
2. From most other sources the peripheral base is 0x3f000000. Why does it say 0x3e000000 here?
3. Combining the above two questions: is the peripheral mapping "eating" some of the VRAM? Because the addresses of the first and second rows overlap with each other.
4. Is it safe to assume Pi2 and Pi3 use the same memory map scheme?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The bottom 4 rows overlap completely with the second row too.  That plus the indent implies the indented rows are breakdowns of the non-indented "heading" row above them.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out! But still, the description make little sense to me. It will be very helpful to me if you could explain more!

Comment: I haven't fiddled with the hardware on that level.  I was just making a quick observation based on the way the table is structured.